# SQL outer join with multiple foreign keys referencing the same table

Tags: sql, outer-join, join

i have a table with

```
P1   P2   P3   P4   P5
ID   ID   NULL ID   NULL
...
```

and a table with

```
ID   Name
ID   xyz
...
```

and want a select this show for example this:

```
P1   P2   P3   P4   P5
Name Name Name Name Name
...
```

I tried it with Join (one and multiple), Select and Multiple FROM, but everytime I have all 5 columns with the IDs or 5 columns and every column contains every name.

Now I am thinking of making a new table and just put every column for itself in there, but I think and hope there is an other way.

EDIT:
My Code:

```
    SELECT 
    TodayPaddock.Paddock1, 
    TodayPaddock.Paddock2
FROM 
    TodayPaddock
Left OUTER JOIN 
Pferde ON Pferde.Id = TodayPaddock.Paddock1  
AND Pferde.Id = TodayPaddock.Paddock2
```

Comment: Can we see the query that you tried?

Comment: SELECT 
 Pferde.Pferdename
FROM 
 Pferde
Right JOIN TodayPaddock AS P1 ON Pferde.Id = P1.Paddock1
Right JOIN TodayPaddock AS P2 ON Pferde.Id = P2.Paddock2


and


SELECT 
 TodayPaddock.Paddock1, TodayPaddock.Paddock2
FROM 
 TodayPaddock
Right JOIN Pferde ON Pferde.Id = TodayPaddock.Paddock1
Right JOIN Pferde ON Pferde.Id = TodayPaddock.Paddock2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need multiple `join`s.  In fact `left join`s:

```
select t2_1.name, t2_2.name, t2_3.name, t2_4.name, t2_5.name
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2_1
     on t1.p1 = t2_1.id left join
     table2 t2_2
     on t1.p2 = t2_2.id left join
     table2 t2_3
     on t1.p3 = t2_3.id left join
     table2 t2_4
     on t1.p4 = t2_4.id left join
     table2 t2_5
     on t1.p5 = t2_5.id;
```

Comment: Thanks, i searched 3 hours for it but wasn't able to make multiple joins ;-D

Answer (score 0):

There is a way with a single outer join. Of course you will want to check the query plan to make sure it's better than the query plan for 5 joins after tuning the indexes, and with a sufficient amount of data. This solution assumes that P1, P2, P3, P4, P5 is a unique key for the TodayPaddock table. If not, you will need to add a unique column to group by, even if it's just an auto-increment column.

```
CREATE TABLE Pferde (
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

INSERT Pferde (ID, Name) VALUES (1, 'NAME1')
INSERT Pferde (ID, Name) VALUES (2, 'NAME2')
INSERT Pferde (ID, Name) VALUES (3, 'NAME3')
INSERT Pferde (ID, Name) VALUES (4, 'NAME4')
INSERT Pferde (ID, Name) VALUES (5, 'NAME5')

CREATE TABLE TodayPaddock (
    P1 INT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Pferde,
    P2 INT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Pferde,
    P3 INT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Pferde,
    P4 INT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Pferde,
    P5 INT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Pferde,
    UNIQUE (P1, P2, P3, P4, P5)
)

INSERT TodayPaddock (P1, P2, P3, P4, P5) VALUES (1, 2, NULL, 4, NULL)
INSERT TodayPaddock (P1, P2, P3, P4, P5) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 3, NULL, 5)

SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN P.ID = TP.P1 THEN P.Name END) AS P1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN P.ID = TP.P2 THEN P.Name END) AS P2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN P.ID = TP.P3 THEN P.Name END) AS P3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN P.ID = TP.P4 THEN P.Name END) AS P4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN P.ID = TP.P5 THEN P.Name END) AS P5
FROM TodayPaddock AS TP
LEFT JOIN Pferde AS P
ON P.ID IN (TP.P1, TP.P2, TP.P3, TP.P4, TP.P5)
GROUP BY TP.P1, TP.P2, TP.P3, TP.P4, TP.P5
```

Results:

```
P1      P2      P3      P4      P5
NULL    NULL    NAME3   NULL    NAME5
NAME1   NAME2   NULL    NAME4   NULL
```

Comment: looks great ^^ will try it next time to build it like that